# HTML 5 video streaming .ism file?

Tags: html, iis, video, streaming, smoothing

I have an IIS 7.0 server setup with Media Services 4.0. I created a very simple html 5 page which containts a `video` with its `source` pointing to a `*.ism` file. Is it possible to play the video using the manifest of the ism file in html 5, like in silverlight?

Here's the html code:

```
<html>
    <body>           
        <video width="640" 
               height="480" 
               src="myvideo.ism/Manifest" 
               autoplay="true" 
               controls="true">vid</video> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Ryan

Comment: One day, I hope, HTML5 supports fragmented mp4 like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorry, but that's not possible.

there few supported formats: webm, ogv and mp4 but not all browsers support all of them.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So the only way really is using an encoder, such as expression encoder and live stream with IIS to a .isml file with a supported format.

Comment: i never heard of isml format. if you have any choice, never use it at all. just go for mp4 which is most widely deployed