# Smooth streaming on browser with HTML5

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to stream smooth streaming video on browser using HTML5? After several trial on IE, Chrome and Firefox, it is still without success.  It seems like smooth streaming only works with SilverLight client or some smoothstreaming application.

Below is the video tag I use:

```
<video controls="controls"
  src="http://smoothhd.code-shop.com/video/oceans.ssm/Manifest"
  poster="poster.jpg"></video>
```

Does anyone know if I have done anything incorrect or it is just not possible to play it with HTML5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML 5 video streaming .ism file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470001/html-5-video-streaming-ism-file)

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently playable in a browser. It is playable within an HTML5 Metro app.

Read for how to do it in a Metro app: http://blogs.iis.net/cenkd/archive/2012/03/28/How-to-build-your-first-html5-metro-style-smooth-streaming-player.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a Silverlight player, which will play that link (if the server has proper crossdomain.xml file).
It's not an equivalent solution of course, but anyway smth that might give you what you're looking for.